# New tag request - 'newbie-friendly'

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

I realise this is unlikely to be added by the newcomer themselves, but sometimes the simplest "LMGTFY" questions are from people new to a given platform/OS; they haven't yet really figured out where to start to look for things.

It sometimes takes a couple of comments back & forth to figure out they really are new rather than 'lazy', which then gives you a chance to put up a 'Platform 101'-type answer for complete newcomers to a given OS.

I'd suggest [new-to](/questions/tagged/new-to) as the overall tag, but split [new-to-mac](/questions/tagged/new-to-mac), [new-to-windows](/questions/tagged/new-to-windows) etc.

This might help gather together this 101-type resource.

A couple of questions have cropped up recently that could benefit from this tag & appropriate newbie-friendly answer, but I don't want to point at one user for this. It's a general issue we do see on occasion.

Comment: These feel a bit too much like meta or commentary tags and I can't say I'm a big fan of the idea of them. You would probably spend just as much time finding out that they were needed than you would just answering their question in the first place. I didn't downvote, it's just my 2p.

Comment: Meta tags, such as the ones you are proposing, are explicitly discouraged in the SE network. The reason for that is discussed in this SO blog post by Jeff Atwood: https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/ The meta tags you suggested are similar to one of the meta tag examples mentioned in that blog post: [beginner].

Answer (score 8):

It *is* unlikely because its a meta tag.

The 'quality' of a question doesn't entirely rely on *specific* subject matter expertise. Its about showing your research or lack thereof and giving folks the information they need to have a chance to answer the question.

Even with an experienced user - there's often many steps and clarifications needed to find an answer sometimes (or at least try to).

*Ideally* they'd *find* the answer here as they are typing out their question (off to the right) or search first for a potential dupe, and a 'novel' newbie level question would have value on our site.

In addition to know the tag was there to be found, a newbie would need to know how things work here, and then they wouldn't be a newbie.

I guess this would be *almost* a community FAQ for specific topics, but the only site that has this is meta.